# How can I crop an image in .NET core?

Tags: c#, image, .net-core, imagesharp

I need to crop images in .NET Core. I used ImageSharp, CoreCompat, and Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility, and scanned all methods I could find. However, I'm still unable to find a method to crop my images. Resizing is there, but not cropping.

How can I crop images in .NET Core based on the upper-left corner's pixel location, width, and height?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/lruckman/fefbe4c02c6e8e1d7d68a18dc1128814) might help for ImageSharp.

Comment: Microsoft documented all approaches you can try, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/ and there can be even more.

Comment: @LexLi, where on that page cropping is mentioned? I don't mean scaling or creating thumbnails. I mean getting the apple image from an apple in the car for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using either [ImageSharp](https://sixlabors.com/projects/imagesharp/) or [CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat)
If you're using ImageSharp, I think this is the proper way to crop an image; using ImageProcessors through the Mutate() method:

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
image.Mutate(ctx => ctx.Crop(width, height));
```

You would need the following namespace to access this:

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
```

Comment: Use System.Drawing.Common instead if you're planning on using CoreCompat.System.Drawing. It ships as part of .NET Core and provides the same functionality, but is better maintained.

Comment: `using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Advanced;`

No you don't. You need `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing`

Answer (score 2):

Just install the following package:

```
System.Drawing.Common package
```

and use the following code:

```
using SD = System.Drawing;

static byte[] Crop(string Img, int Width, int Height, int X, int Y)
{
    try
    {
        using (SD.Image OriginalImage = SD.Image.FromFile(Img))
        {
            using (SD.Bitmap bmp = new SD.Bitmap(Width, Height))
            {
                bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);

                using (SD.Graphics Graphic = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                    Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                    Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), X, Y, Width, Height, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                    bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);

                    return ms.GetBuffer();

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw (Ex);
    }
}
```

This answer is based on a great article [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/95/upload-and-crop-images-with-jquery-jcrop-and-asp-net). However, with the modification to work under .net Core 2.x and above by just installing the mentioned package. By the way, other famous packages are using the same core libraries.

As you can see, you have more flexibility in cropping than the famous libraries mentioned in other answers.

Comment: More flexibility? Don't spread FUD. Also don't use `ms.GetBuffer()` that can be a byte array larger than the written pixel data

Comment: Regarding FUD three years later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageSharp library](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp). It has method that crop image based on the upper-left corner. Look at the example below:

```
private async static Task CropImage()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png")
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        using (var inputStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            using (var image = Image.Load(inputStream))
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "foo.png");

                image.Clone(
                    ctx => ctx.Crop(560, 300)).Save(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Crop also has an overload that accepts a Rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

First install the package "System.Drawing.Common".

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

...

```
public byte[] Crop(string path, int width, int height)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    bmp.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle rect, PixelFormat format), for example, as a Bitmap extension:

```
using System.Drawing;

static public class BitmapExtensions
{
    static public Bitmap Crop(this Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle rect)
    {
        return bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    }
}
```