# Crop image .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I'm trying to implement an image cropper or to create a custom view that sits on top of what camera sees and display the crop.

For image cropper I'm trying to create an IDrawable that sits on top of an image with a fixed cropped center and the user would be able to pan and pitch the image to adjust the crop but I would like for the image to be still and to be able to move that crop area around but I don't know how.

And for the camera overlay I have no idea from where to start.

I keep reading for solutions for both approaches but with not much success.
Some link to some nice presented ideas would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Preferably no unknown 3rd party

Comment: https://github.com/jbowmanp1107/ImageCropper.Maui

Comment: without _unknown_ third party: [How can I crop an image in .NET core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955644/how-can-i-crop-an-image-in-net-core)

Comment: Everyone on SO is an “unknown third party”.  It’s a GitHub link.  Read the code and then implement your own solution

Comment: For the camera overlay, add your image with transparency to a WebView. The WebView will be on top (eg ZIndex=1) and the camera view ZIndex should be lower (eg ZIndex=2).

Comment: The nuget sugested by Jason works